# How to register handler interceptors with spring mvc 3.0?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

It should be easy:

```
<bean id="handlerMapping"
   class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="interceptors">
        <list>
            <ref bean="myInterceptor" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

but this way the interceptor isn't called.

Comment: Do you also have `<mv:annotation-driven/>` in there somewhere?

Comment: Yes, in order to activate javax.validation handling (and perhaps a pile of other things)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

By default, Spring will register a `BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping`, and a `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping`, without any explicit config required.

If you define your own `HandlerMapping` beans, then the default ones will not be registered, and you'll just get the explicitly declared ones.

So far, so good.

The problem comes when you add `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` to the mix. This *also* declares its own `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping`, which replaces the defaults. However, if you also declare your own one, then you end up with two. Since they are consulted in order of declaration, this usually means the one registered by `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` gets called first, and your own one gets ignored.

It would be better if the `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` registered by `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` acted like the default one, i.e. if explicitly declared ones took precedence, but that's not the way they wrote it.

My current preference is to not use `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` at all, it's too confusing, and too unpredictable when mixed with other config options. It doesn't really do anything especially complex, it's not difficult or verbose to explicitly add the stuff that it does for you, and the end result is easier to follow.

Comment: Good explanation. marking it as accepted. I'll ask another question with what remains unclear - i.e. how to activate parts of what mvc:annotation-driven is doing.

Comment: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-6524 seems there is an issue for that, and Juergen Hoeller's comments that this is intended.

Comment: `<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />` - no need of another question :)

Comment: what we use instead of `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` ?

Answer (score 13):

*Problem I faced*: Spring MVC  tag doesn't go well with custom definition of DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.

Why..? the reason is very well explained in the answers above.

***Why i wanted to use DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping***? I want to define an interceptor for my every request. a Spring-Mobile interceptor to determine the USER AGENT..mobile or a browser?

Now Due to this clash of **mvc-annotation** and **DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping**, I cant use DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping anymore. 
The problem comes down to how can i register my interceptors with  tag.

**The solution** was simple...but hard to find. Posting it so it can be helpful to the other solution seekers..
Use    tag and register the interceptor bean in your dispathcer-servlet.xml
**example** :

```
<mvc:interceptors>
 <!-- This runs for all mappings -->
     <bean  class="main.com.XXX.MobileDeviceResolverHanlderInterceptor"/>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Comment: i am already put these tags in my `xxx-servlet.xml` file, but still facing the error.

Answer (score 9):

The reason for this behaviour is that two beans of type `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` exist in the application context. Spring resolves the two, but asks only the first for interceptors. To fix this, the following init parameter should be set to the `DispatcherServlet`

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>detectAllHandlerMappings</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</init-param>
```

This makes the dispatcher servlet use only the `handlerMapping` defined in the `x-servlet.xml`

It is beyond me why this is the default behaviour. I'm expecting an answer from the spring community.

Comment: The defaults when using the `<mvc>` namespace are wildly confusing. I prefer the older style of specifying everything yourself - the namespace configuration methods seem to rely too much on not-easily-found-in-documentation defaults

Answer (score 6):

In my case I can NOT get rid of `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` as I am using jackson for json support using annotation.

What I tried, moved my all interceptors `<mvc:interceptors>` in separate "xml" file (interceptor-config.xml) and imported it from my x-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<import resource="interceptor-config.xml"/>
```

It solve my issue and avoid default 'DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping' beans my application context.

Rather than creating separate 'xml', you can copy/paste interceptor contents directly in 'x-dispatcher-servlet.xml'.

Following is my interceptor:

```
  <mvc:interceptors> 
         <mvc:interceptor>
             <!-- Intercepting specific URL -->
             <mvc:mapping path="/abc/**" />
             <bean id= "myInterceptor" 
                 class="xx.xxx.xxx.MyInterceptor" />
         </mvc:interceptor>
<mvc:interceptors>
```

Answer (score 3):

In Spring MVC 3.0 you can use [`<mvc:interceptors>`](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/12/21/mvc-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/) instead of manual defining the handler mapping.

Comment: @Bozho: You can use a `BeanReferenceFactoryBean` (yes, I know that it's ugly).