# Spring MVC: enable flash messages without having <mv:annotation-driven/> in spring-servlet.xml?

Tags: spring-mvc

I am hoping to use Spring flash messages. One way to enable it is to use `<mv:annotation-driven/>` in spring-servlet.xml. However, it causes problems to other parts of the application, and I found the explanation here

[How to register handler interceptors with spring mvc 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230633/how-to-register-handler-interceptors-with-spring-mvc-3-0)

I have interceptors defined in spring-servlet.xml

```
<bean id="handlerMapping"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"> 
    <property name="interceptors"> 
        <list>
        interceptors
        </list> 
    </property>
</bean>
```

I tried the use of `<mv:annotation-driven/>` plus moving interceptors under `<mvc:interceptors>`, but it caused other problems.

So IF I want to use the flash messages tool, can I make it work without having 
`<mv:annotation-driven/>` or using `<mvc:interceptors>` in spring-servlet.xml?

Regards and thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was just looking at this myself and found this post that may be useful to you.
[Using the Flash scope ( and RedirectAttributes ) without <mvc:annotation-driven /> in Spring MVC 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960410/using-the-flash-scope-and-redirectattributes-without-mvcannotation-driven)

Comment: Please include the relevant piece of code in your answer