# spring 3.0.5 <mvc:interceptor> not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, interceptor

I am trying to create an interceptor to log the http request details before a call to the controller happens. My spring xml is

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"

xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd"
    >

<context:component-scan base-package="com.xxx.controller" />

<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
    <mvc:mapping path="/**" />
    <bean class="com.xxx.interceptor.LogBillingInterceptor">
</bean>
</mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

My interceptor class

```
public class LogBillingInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter{

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("sdfsdfdsfd");
    return super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
}

@Override
public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
        ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("aaaaaaaasdfsdfdsfd");
    super.postHandle(request, response, handler, modelAndView);
}

@Override
public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex)
        throws Exception {
    System.out.println("qqqqqqqqqqsdfsdfdsfd");
    super.afterCompletion(request, response, handler, ex);

}
```

}

But it doesnt seem to work. I am using spring 3.0.5

i just saw that we are using spring-oauth2 and use the following.

```
<http access-denied-page="/error" access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"  entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">

    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/**" access="ROLE_USER" />

    <intercept-url pattern="/store/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/balance/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/tapjoy" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />

    <intercept-url pattern="/verify_credentials" access="ROLE_USER" />

    <intercept-url pattern="/welcome/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/logout/**" access="ROLE_USER" />

    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/loginfailed" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />

    <intercept-url pattern="/request_token_authorized.jsp" access="ROLE_USER,DENY_OAUTH" />

        <custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="tpAuthenticationFilter" />
</http>
```

Can we add interceptors with Spring security..

Comment: doubt if it could be Spring Security @harshit, Spring Security intercepts before the DispatcherServlet gets the request, via filters, and interceptors handle the request just before the controllers are invoked.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely because of the handlerMapping created by `mvc:annotation-driven`, the best recommendation that I have seen is to remove `mvc:annotation-driven`, replace with an explicit bean definition for the appropriate HandlerAdapter(`AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` in 3.0), and explicitly specify a `handlerMapping` as a property with the interceptors defined there.

[How to register handler interceptors with spring mvc 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3230633/204788)

Comment: i guess thats valid for spring 3.1 and i am using 3.0.5 and the xml show errors.

Comment: Yes, that's true @harshit, it is not valid for 3.1 also - this link has a better answer - http://stackoverflow.com/q/3230633/204788